# The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element with Android Studio Android Manifest XML File

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I recently got into Android Studio and Android Java development. I had this error come up when I was working on the Android Manifest file. My file layout for the project is as is below...

[image: Project File Layout]

The goal here is to get my Java Class to  become the Main Activity by declaring it as an activity but I have been looking on different forums and questions on StackOverflow and I wasn't able to find an answer. I don't know if I can even make a Java Class the Main Activity for the application. Here is the XML File...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.package">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The activity I am trying to declare as an activity is that file you see named MainActivity in the `app` folder. I am really unsure about how to properly structure the project to allow that file to become the primary app while also adjusting my Android Manifest file. I am also using Firebase in the MainActivity Class

Comment: Voted to close for being a typo: Your `application` element is directly closed: `<application ... />`. It should be `<application ...>` with a `</application>` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have terminated the `application` tag, which you should not have:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" **/**>
```

Should be

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The correct manifest should be something like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```